# regex - decimalised number

Tags: regex, decimal

I'm very new to regex. How do I match a decimalised number. I have found ones that include $ but just need to match any number which could include decimals.

e.g.

100
100.50
707.40
150.00

Comment: what have you tried?  if you found one that includes $, have you thought about how to remove the $ to get what you want?  i bet you can figure it out with a little thought.  give it a shot.  i believe in you.

Comment: There are many, many, many answers here on SO on how to match numbers, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

Answer (score 0):

It's not very advanced, but:

```
/\d.*?\.\d.*/
```

Will match:

2.0
12.00

Won't match:

2
22

Doesn't check if it's a number though.