# EditText (Currency) validation in android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I want to set EditText validation,

Only contains number, size 4 digit for decimal, and 2 digit for fraction value..total 6 digit,

I also want just enter only number form number pad. if i am select any non numeric number then EditText will not accept it.

if any suggestion, it would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: you can use  regex so it should be 1024.22 something like this??

Comment: @vrajesh have look at this link  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

that will help you.

Comment: @Raghunandan can i use TextWatcher Listener ? if yes then in which method i put my logic ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

attribute for `EditText`

You can use a regex for the validation part. The below is only a sample

You can check with a online regex tester @ http://regex101.com/r/uG9aF6/1

```
String input = "1024.22";
String pattern = "([0-9]{4})(\.)([0-2]{2})"; // 4 digits followe by . followed by 2 digits
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
if(m.matches())
{
   System.out.println("Validated");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("Not Validated");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:inputType ="number"` and `android:maxLength="6"` in xml layout of `editText` will popup the **keypad of digits** and only six digits can be entered in the `editText`

> like this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/myinput"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:hint="@string/somestring"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Comment: This should help but he also wants to have a specific format for the input to be enforced.

Comment: op needs `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern  ^([0-9]{1,4})(.[0-9]{1,2})?$

it accepts up-to 4 digits before . and only up-to 2 after

Answer (score 0):

You can check your period position. For example 
in your case

`char value = 'anychar' ;
if (edittext.gettext.toString().indexOf(value) == 4 ){ // your logic  goes here }`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:maxLength="7" />
```

4 - digits for Number , 1 - digits for .(Dot) and 2- Digits for fraction Number.
Its also Number Decimal SoftKeyboard when you made focus on Edittext.

if you want to focus on Edittext auto use this:

```
          android:focusable="true"
```