# Regex expression is not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regex expression with this requirement .

**Requirement :**

*Max length* - 5(inc decimal dot if is a decimal number)

*Decimal precession* - max 2 digits (if it is a decimal numer ).

*Number* - need not to be a decimal number (not mandatory)

**Code:**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var regexp = /^(?!\.?$)\d{0,5}(\.\d{0,2})?$/;
    var num = 12345.52; // i will test here indiffernt ways
    var n = regexp.test(num)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n; // returns true or false
}
</script>
```

**Output should look like :**

12345.52 -->It should return `false` as length is 8 inc dot but it returns `true`

123456.52 --> false . I came to know `d{0,5}` is looking for before decimal

12.45 --> true . Perfect one (length 5 , precession 2 )

12345 --> true . Perfect one (length 5 , precession- not madatory)

I am hoping to build a regex expression satisfies all the above scenarios .

Reference : [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

Comment: What you wrote will return false...what abot `12345 `?

Comment: did you want to allow `1.2`?

Comment: `TusharGupta` sadly it returns true & `12345` should return `false` . ` user3558931` yes it does return bool but i am getting some wrong output as mentioned in my scenarios . ` Avinash Raj` yes offcourse as max length is 5 i do .

Comment: Because you are not restricting your maximum limit. When I read your regexp it's perfectly valid to have `ddddd.dd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^(?=.{1,5}$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO6fW3/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?=.{1,5}$)` Asserts that the length must be from 1 upto 5.
- `\d+` Allows one or more digits.
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Optional decimal part with the allowable digits after the decimal point must be one or two.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end of the line.

Comment: cant thank you more buddie. sadly there is small correction in my question requirement can i edit or should i post as a new one ?

Comment: ask me . If i don't know the answer then you go for edit(**no**) or another question. Say your new requirement.

Comment: forget about length now i just need regex for a number if it is integer it should be 3 digits max and if its decimal it should be of 3 digit max before dot and precession of 2 max like `123.45`