# Livecycle RegExp - trouble with decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, livecycle

Within Livecycle, I am validating that the number entered is a 0 through 10 and allows quarter hours. With the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2), I've written the following.

```
if (!xfa.event.newText.match(/^(([10]))$|^((([0-9]))$|^((([0-9]))\.?((25)|(50)|(5)|(75)|(0)|(00))))$/))
    {
        xfa.event.change = "";
    };
```

The problem is periods are not being accepted.  I have tried wrapping the `\.` in parenthesis but that did not work either. The field is a text field with no special formatting and the code in the change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes, that's a convoluted regex. This can be simplified a lot:

```
/^(?:10|[0-9](?:\.(?:[27]?5)?0*)?)$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
^             # Start of string
(?:           # Start of group:
 10           # Either match 10
|             # or
 [0-9]        # Match 0-9
 (?:          # optionally followed by this group:
  \.          # a dot
  (?:[27]?5)? # either 25, 75 or 5 (also optional)
  0*          # followed by optional zeroes
 )?           # As said before, make the group optional
)             # End of outer group
$             # End of string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rG1tX4/1).

Comment: Thank you for including the explanation! It is almost working, it won't accept the `2` or `7`.

Comment: @silviak: Not sure what you mean. It should accept `25` or `75`, and it shouldn't accept `2` or `7`, right? I've added a live preview at regex101.

Comment: Testing `.25` or `.75`, when I type in `.25` it will not accept the `2` and skips over to the `5`. I'm thinking maybe because it is on the change event and it looking for the entire string?

Comment: Oh, so you're checking the input as you type? Not a good idea - if `0.7` is invalid and `0.75` is valid, how should the computer know that you intend to type another `5` after the `0.7`? Validation should only be done after you've submitted the entry.