# Patterns For Only Numeric & Dot. Eg : 120 / 120.03 / -123.03 / 0.32

Tags: javascript, validation

I need a pattern for only **Numeric & dot**.
 `Eg : 120 / 120.03 / -123.03 / 0.32` whole number and decimal digits are user defined.
Whole numbers & decimals may less then the user defined. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, can't find the code…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

Comment: check this: /\d\.?/g

Comment: @PM77-1 , in the specified case, if user defined decimal was 3 then it should allow upto 3. Eg : 3 / 3.1 / 3.11 / 3.111. how to resolve this.

Comment: Thank you all. got the pattern based on above. I used "^[-+]?(\d{1,4})(\.\d{1,4})?$".