# Laravel double validation regex not working

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm trying to validate a double with two decimals but I can't achieve that.
This is the regex and the errors I tryied and I got:

First try:

```
$validation = ['price' => 'regex:[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?'];
```

Error:

> preg_match(): Unknown modifier '+'

Second try:

```
$validation = ['price' => 'regex:[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?'];
```

Error:

> preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Third try:

```
$validation = ['price' => 'regex:\d+(\.\d{2})?|\.\d{2}'];
```

Error:

> preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

I got all the regex from this question: [Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

What am I doing wrong? Or there is any other way to validate a double with two decimals in `Laravel`?

Comment: Try `$validation = ['price' => 'regex:/[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/'];`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you it works, but is it any way to prevent more than two decimals?

Comment: You mean to only allow, say, `1.22` and not `1.233`? Try `$validation = ['price' => 'regex:/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$/'];`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, thank you very much !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use regex delimiters, the most common ones are `/.../`. Also, to make sure you match the entire string, you need anchors, `^` to anchor at the start and `$` to anchor at the end:

```
$validation = ['price' => 'regex:/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$/'];
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code here below

```
'column' => 'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to improve Wiktor answer this part is used `[0-9][0-9]?` to check if we have one or two digits after decimal points where `[0-9]?` second one is optional. So this can be simplified by following

```
'regex:/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/'
```

Here `{1,2}` tells how many digits we want after decimal point here at least one. So if someone wants more digits to be fixed e.g any want at most 3 digits after decimal point just change `{1,2}` to `{1,3}`.

Also to validate also negative numbers

```
'regex:/^(-)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/'
```

Here adding `(-)?` checks optional minus numbers.