# Regex for number between special characters

Tags: regex

I want to build a regex that will extract me numbers from a string. The pattern is

```
">number<"
```

Now the number can have decimals or not.
I went with:

```
"[^\d]+"
```

This does extract the numbers but because of decimals, it sometimes works bad. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is this similar question of any help by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>((\-|\+)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)<
```

Explained:

- `(\-|\+)?` optional sign: `-` or `+`
- `[0-9]+` - non-empty sequence of digits
- `(\.[0-9]+)?` - optional sequence starting with a dot followed by non-empty sequence of digits
- `>` and `<` at the beginning and at the and (not in the matching group)

In the first matching group you will have your number.

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/sLeFmO/1).

Comment: `1.` could be a valid format for a float, depending on the language writing the number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (copy with the quotes):

```
">[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?<"
```

Comment: You need to escape the dot.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex which works for integers, floats and negative numbers :

```
>([\+\-]?\d+\.?\d*)<
```

The number is in group 1.

If you can use positive lookarounds, this regex matches just a number between `><` and nothing else :

```
(?<=>)[\+\-]?\d+\.?\d*(?=<)
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/HGGsyW/3) in action.

Comment: I'ts good that you have added `-` for negative numbers, but it also matches for example `>--4-4-4---.-.-..--..-.-.-<`...

Comment: Garbage in -> Garbage out :D. But you're right, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's just the number you want:

```
(?<=\\>)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(?=\<)
```

It matches any number with or without decimals between `>` and `<` but **excluding** `>` and `<`