# RegEx - Decimal With a Precision of 2 Or Malformed Number

Tags: regex, numbers, decimal-point

I need a RegEx pattern that will match on a valid decimal number string with two decimal places, or a malformed number only if the malformed number is an integer with a decimal place at the end.

This is a good discussion on achieving a match on two decimal places

[Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

But, I need these following strings to match:

Match:

- 3432.56
- 3434
- 3432.8
- 7645.0
- 343. **(Special case)**

Not Matched:

- Cheese
- 3434/78
- 43424.654

FYI: This is for masking an input field so that the user can enter any two digit number. The problem currently is that the field rejects the decimal place because it doesn't recognize it as a decimal number unless the user hits the left button to take the cursor back a character and then presses the decimal point key.

Comment: How about this? `^\d+\.\d{0,2}$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U2EhzU/2)

Comment: That's pretty close but it won't allow me to delete the decimal point.

Comment: Can't we make the whole decimal thing optional like this `^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`? [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/U2EhzU/3)

Comment: I think this is perfect. I'm just doing some testing to make sure it's a perfect fit.

Comment: Yep. Please propose this as the answer.

Comment: I have proposed it as the answer. Is it not what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U2EhzU/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - start of the string
- `\d+` - matches 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d{0,2})?` - matches a decimal followed by 0 to 2 digits. `?` makes this whole part optional so as to allow the Integers too.
- `$` - End of the String

Comment: FYI: This is code where this RegEx is leveraged to create a masked Text Box in Xamarin Forms which works on all platforms: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation/blob/master/Adapt.Presentation.Standard/Adapt/Presentation/Behaviours/EntryPatternMatchValidationBehaviour.cs