# Regular expression for decimal number up to 2 precision and characters

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expression and I am trying to form a regular expression for below scenarios having combination of letters and decimal number upto 2 precision:

```
GBP 23.44   -> Valid

23.44       -> Valid

23          -> Valid

23 GBP      -> Valid

234.44 GBP  -> Valid

234.44      -> Valid

23.334 GBP  -> Invalid

234.443 GBP -> Invalid

234& GBP    -> Invalid
```

Moreover no other characters should be allowed other than A-Z and a-z and Number with 2 precisions.

**My attempt**:

I tried `^[Aa-Zz][0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`, but its not working as per the expression numbers always needed to be followed after characters like `234.44 GBP` is failing to match.

I am not able to form exact expression which satisfy all the scenarios. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide your failed attempt?

Comment: I think this or similar is answered in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

Comment: @achAmháin I tried ^[Aa-Zz][0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$ but its not working ans as per expression  numbers always need to be followed after characters so 234.44 GBP this is failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looks like only matches to be rejected are where number has 3 decimal places and GBP doesn't matter as long as it is accompanied by a number. You may use this regex,

```
^(?!\d+\.\d{3})[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*$
```

Demo here,
https://regex101.com/r/1HlV8z/2

Let me know if it works fine for you or you have any other custom needs.

Edit1:
Updated my regex to meet your valid character needs. Valid characters allowed shall be upper/lower alphabets, numbers, dot and space.

Comment: I forgot to mention that no charcters should be allowed other then this

Comment: I have updated my answer to meet your valid character needs. Check the new link in answer for demo

Comment: Pleased to help :)