# Regex to match numbers between 0 to 25 both inclusive which can be doubles with 1 precision

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to use Regex to match numbers between 0 to 25 both inclusive which can be doubles with 1 precision.

For ex.- 2, 2.5, 23.0, 8, 24.3, 25

I created following regex-

```
^(\\s*|0?[0-9]|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])$
```

But it works only for numbers between 0 to 25 both inclusive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

Comment: Why do this with a regular expression?

Comment: @Barmar Easy answer.  So I can post and get some points.  Duh!

Comment: @Barmar- I am using http://schemaform.io/ and it requires regex as a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex pattern I would use here:

```
^(?:(?:[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])(?:\.[0-9])?|25(?:\.0)?)$
```

### Demo

The pattern is similar to what you used, except that we only match `2[0-4]` with any single decimal point.  The end point 25 is a special case, which can only take `25.0` at most for its decimal component.

But in general it would easier in JavaScript to just parse the text number, and then use an inequality to check the range.  E.g.

```
var number = '24.3'
if (number >= 0 && number <= 25.0) {
    console.log('within range');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To verify the validity, use the `>=` and `<=` operators. To meet the regex requirement, just add a garbage regex expression.

```
let isMatch = number => {
  'must use regex'.match(/x/);
  return number >= 0 && number <= 25;
};
```