# Regular Expressions to Match Decimal 12,2 With Comma to Separate Groups of Thousands

Tags: php, regex, decimal

I want to make sure that the input is no more than 10 digits before the decimals point so it will match DECIMAL(12,2).

I already tried :

```
^(?=.{0,13}$)[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

But it counts the digits after decimals too, so what I want to match is:

1,111,111,111.00

so it will keep matching with or without the decimals, what I tried only can match with:

1,111,111,111

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert from the start of the string what is on the right is 1-10 times a digit followed by an optional comma followed by a dot and 2 digits.

Then use the pattern to match the exact format.

**Note** that in your pattern the `(\.[0-9]+)?` at the end can match more than 2 digits. If you want to match an optional dot and 2 digits, use `(?:\.[0-9]{2})?`

```
^(?=(?:\d,?){1,10}(?:\.\d{2})?$)[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HfKBNi/1)

Comment: Thanks, it fits what I want, I will accept it when it already can be accepted